# Checking if username is available before submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to check if the username is taken before the form is submitted.

As far as I can understand I have to use AJAX to get data from my database in javascript. How do I send the username to the PHP file?

This is my form:

```html
<form id="loginForm" action="register.php" method="post">
    <p>Register:</p>
    <p style="text-align: left;">Full name: <br><input type="text" name="name" required/></p>
    <p style="text-align: left;">Email: <br><input type="text" name="email" required/></p>

    //Username
    <p style="text-align: left;">Username: <br><input id="username" type="text" name="username" onkeyup="validateUsername(value);" required/></p>
    <span id="usernameError" style="display:none;border:1px solid red;">Username can only contain a-z, 0-9 and must be at least 6 characters loong</span>
    <span id="usernameTaken" style="display:none;border:1px solid red;">Username taken</span>

    <p style="text-align: left;">Password: <br><input type="password" name="password" required/></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

This is the `validateUsername()` function:

```js
function validateUsername(username) {
    var re = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/;
    alert(username.length);
    if(re.test(username) && username.length > 5) {
        document.getElementById('username').style.backgroundColor = "green";
        document.getElementById('usernameError').style.display= "none";
        --error;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('username').style.backgroundColor = "red";
        document.getElementById('usernameError').style.display= "block";
        ++error;
    }
    //here i want to check if the user name is taken
}
```

If the username is taken, I want to display the 'usernameTaken' span.
Otherwise, I want to hide it.

Here is the PHP file that checks if the username is already in the database:

```js
<?php
session_start();
define('DB_NAME', 'madsanker_dk_db');
define('DB_USER', 'madsanker_dk');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'MyPassword');
define('DB_HOST', 'mysql43.unoeuro.com');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' .mysqli_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db( $link, DB_NAME);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Could not connect: ' .mysqli_connect_error());
}

$username = //The username;
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$username);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mainLogin WHERE username = '$username'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 0) {
    //if the username is NOT taken
    return true;
} else {
    //if the username IS taken
    return false;
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

How is this done?

Comment: U can use ajax send username to Php by using element id or jquery

Comment: where is your problem in this code? Have you tested that username goes in ajax request correctly.

Comment: The PHP should return a document of some kind, it's not a function return. The most simple example would be to just print `"true"` or `"false"`. The **a** -jax call is **a** -synchronous, so disable the submit button in the verify function and then re-enable it when the callback from the ajax says all is good e.g. `if (this.response === "true");` (or after some reasonable timeout, e.g. 2 seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JS - JQUERY AJAX**

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'register.php', data: {action: 'isUserNameTaken', params: [username]},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        //Do Something
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```js
<?php
function isUserNameTaken($username) {
    //Do Something;
}

if(!empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'isUserNameTaken':
            $username = '';

            if(!empty($_POST['params'])) {
                $username = $_POST['params'][0];
            }

            isUserNameTaken($username);

            break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `isset && !empty` is nonsensical, use just `!empty`.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for your comment, I edited my answer though to be honest am not a PHP developer i just found the question did a quick research and wanted to share the results i came up with :)

Answer (score -1):

You could do it this way:
On client side:

```
function validateUsername(){
   if(//test username input for length...) {
   $.ajax({  
         type: 'POST',  
         url: 'validate.php', 
         data: { username: username },
         success: function(response) {
              if(response==0){
                 //username is valid
               }
              elseif(response==1){
               //username is already taken
              }
              elseif(response==2){
                //connection failed 
              }

         }
   });
  }
  else{
     //display "username is too short" error
  }

}
```

validate.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
define('DB_NAME', 'madsanker_dk_db');
define('DB_USER', 'madsanker_dk');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'MyPassword');
define('DB_HOST', 'mysql43.unoeuro.com');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
  die('Could not connect: ' .mysqli_error());
   echo json_encode(2);
}
 else{
   $db_selected = mysqli_select_db( $link, DB_NAME);

   if (!$db_selected) {
      die('Could not connect: ' .mysqli_connect_error());
       echo json_encode(2);
    }
    else{
       $username = $_POST["username"];
       $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$username);

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM mainLogin WHERE username = '$username'";

       $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

       $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
       if($count == 0) {
         //if the username is NOT taken
         echo json_encode(0); 
       }else {
          //if the username IS taken
             echo json_encode(1);
        }
        mysqli_close($link);
    }


 }

?>
```

You can also make this function validateUsername by calling it with onkeyup function in jquery so every time a user types something into the input field, the username will be checked....

Comment: Why would you like to add jQuery for just a simple ajax request when it is not used anywhere else?

Comment: Well, by using onkeyup, you could check the database every time the user types something into it,  Mads Anker doesnt want to submit the form and then check the username right? So this is a way that could be done.

Comment: That would be a terrible idea @Tom. You wouldn't like to DoS your own server. SQL queries can be a bit expensive and when done like 10s of times a second by every user out of thousands of users on site (lets assume), it'll be fatal to server.

Comment: @MehulMohan What do you suggest i do without using jQuery?

Comment: @MadsAnkerNielsen use XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Hmm you are right, but what if the ajax is fired lets say 2 seconds after the user types something into input? Would that be any better?

Comment: Thanks Guys. I will go look up how to use "XMLHttpRequest".